# Using querySelectorAll to filter option tags with specific values

Tags: javascript

I know I can query all option tags like this.

```
document.querySelectorAll("option")
```

I can also query all options tags with only specific values like this.

```
document.querySelectorAll("option[value='abc']")
```

Is there a way to only query options tags that have a value?  So something like this?

```
document.querySelectorAll("option[value!='']")
```

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, that would match `<option value>` by the looks of it OP wants options that have non-empty value

Comment: @PatrickEvans Probably unnecessary, but `option[value]:not([value=''])` if you must.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "**not**", as suggested by Niet in the comment but you don't have to use "value" with option.

```
<select>
        <option value="1">cleaning</option>
        <option value="2">food-2</option>
        <option value="3">toilet</option>
        <option value="4">baby</option>
        <option value="6">knick-knacks</option>
        <option value="9">junk-2</option>
        <option value="10">cosmetics</option>
    </select>

console.log(document.querySelectorAll('option:not([value="3"])'))
```

See the working fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/vdaa79pk/

Comment: yep, as I mentioned that Niet has replied already. This was more of an extension to check any specific value. Good work mate.